# Correct Terminology of Types of Users of a Software Application

Tags: terminology, programming, interpersonal-relations

Maybe I should ask this in a language forum? I am not in an English country, so maybe that's why I can't know for sure the word I am looking for.

I'm designing a system that will have multiple modules. It is even possible that these modules are separated into different applications. Then it came a question I had previously asked myself but I could not get the answer:

What names should I give to different types of users of the modules of a system? Is there a current default pattern?

Existing example: Uber

Uber, with its "drivers users" and "passengers users", has an application for each of these types of users. Uber states that drivers are their partners and not employees (and not customers). But what about the passengers? Are they customers of Uber or customers of the drivers? Do you understand where I want to go?

My case:

In the case of my project, my client would be a number of different professionals who would be the source of money income for the system (so they would be my clients), and they would be users of a 'apk' module built only for them. These clients have their own clients, who would use another separate 'apk' module to use the services of the professionals already mentioned. These users (clients of my clients) would not pay to use the system. In addition, there are the users who administer my clients, using a CRM module that will be made for them.

In the end, there are at least 4 types of users:

- My customers
- Customers of my customers
- Employees of my customers, with more restricted access profile to work for my customers in the application
- Managers of my customers (my collaborators which have client wallets)

**So, how should you name each module and its users? knowing that there is still the open module, which can be accessed without the need for authentication...**

Dirty example:

1. Customers Module (some medics for example)
2. Customers Clients Module + Public Areas Module (patients for example)
3. CRM Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at it as a diagram, this is the structure you've described:

My Customers
-> Customers
-> Employees
-> Managers

Stripping out the redundancy of the last three user types all "being of" your customers, that leaves four unique terms: *my customers*, *customers*, *employees*, and *managers*.

That's the end of any objective analysis I can do for your situation and what you might name things. The rest would end up being a matter of subjective opinion.

Hopefully this is suggestive enough to help in some way.